# Dreamweaver CS6 - unwanted formatting copying from MS Word

Tags: html, ms-word, formatting, dreamweaver

My issue: I have a word document with content used to created a static html page. I am able to copy/paste the content into Design View. Unfortunately...and predictably...I am getting unwanted formatting (i.e. ordered and unordered lists, non-breaking spaces, etc). I have tried to save word doc as .html .rft .pdf and copy/paste from there. Same situation. I've inspected the .doc looking for formatting characters. I haven't found any.

Adding the content to Code view omits all the desired formatting and styles.

Comment: Have you tried to save it as a .txt file? Or pasting it into Notepad first? That should get rid of any formatting

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but it removes all my desired styling. :(

Answer (score 1):

To retain the formatting and styles you do want, I suggest using tinymce's try it editor. It's good for a quick fix to remove special, funky characters from Word. You can then open from source code and copy that into your Dreamweaver's source code area.

https://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: I'm hesitant to download to my employer's equipment. Is this a verifiable product?

Comment: I tried the interactive. That greatly improved formatting without removing styling. Still inserted a few non-breaking spaces, but I can live with that and do a mass find/replace. TY :)

Comment: Not perfect...now I'm getting paragraph tags inserted where there were none. One step forward, two steps back. :( At least my original problem was predictable. I wish I could inpsect what is causing this from MS Word and strip out those characters.

Comment: It's not perfect, but it does kill all special characters MS Word tries to port over. This one might give you a better output: http://www.textfixer.com/html/convert-word-to-html.php